# How to use findMany in Drizzle ORM?

Tags: supabase, drizzle, drizzle-orm

I'm using Supabase too. I'm getting this error:

```yaml
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findMany')
    at Module.getAllRestaurantsByVendor (projectfolder/src/modules/restaurant/db.ts:22:74)
    at Module.GET (projectfolder/src/pages/api/restaurant/index.ts:17:48)
    at eval (projectfolder/src/pages/restaurant/index.astro:27:46)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async callComponentAsTemplateResultOrResponse (file:///projectfolder/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/runtime/server/render/astro/render.js:87:25)
    at async renderToAsyncIterable (file:///projectfolder/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/runtime/server/render/astro/render.js:115:26)
    at async renderPage (file:///projectfolder/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/runtime/server/render/page.js:31:24)
    at async Response.status (file:///projectfolder/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/core/render-context.js:80:25)
    at async callMiddleware (file:///projectfolder/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/core/middleware/callMiddleware.js:11:10)        
    at async RenderContext.render (file:///projectfolder/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/core/render-context.js:96:22)
Error: Error in getAllRestaurantsByVendor: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findMany')
    at Module.getAllRestaurantsByVendor (projectfolder/src/modules/restaurant/db.ts:33:11)
    at Module.GET (projectfolder/src/pages/api/restaurant/index.ts:17:48)
    at eval (projectfolder/src/pages/restaurant/index.astro:27:46)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async callComponentAsTemplateResultOrResponse (file:///projectfolder/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/runtime/server/render/astro/render.js:87:25)
    at async renderToAsyncIterable (file:///projectfolder/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/runtime/server/render/astro/render.js:115:26)
    at async renderPage (file:///projectfolder/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/runtime/server/render/page.js:31:24)
    at async Response.status (file:///projectfolder/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/core/render-context.js:80:25)
    at async callMiddleware (file:///projectfolder/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/core/middleware/callMiddleware.js:11:10)        
    at async RenderContext.render (file:///projectfolder/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/core/render-context.js:96:22)
```

I'm trying to use findMany in @modules/restaurant/db.ts which is used in a GET request at /api/restaurant

```js
import db from "@lib/db";
try {
  const result = await db.query.Restaurants.findMany({
    where: eq(restaurants.vendor_id, vendor_id),
    columns: {
      id: true,
    }
  })
  
  return result;
} catch (error) {
  throw new Error("Error in getAllRestaurantsByVendor: " + error);
}
```

this is my schema at @lib/schema.ts

```js
import {
  timestamp,
  pgTable,
  text,
  integer,
  boolean,
  pgEnum,
  jsonb,
} from "drizzle-orm/pg-core";
import type { NodePgDatabase } from "drizzle-orm/node-postgres";
import { serial } from "drizzle-orm/pg-core";
import { roles, subscription, paymentType } from "@/constant/db";
import type { constants } from "@/constant/db";

export const UserRoleEnum = pgEnum(
  "UserRole",
  roles.map((r: constants) => r.value) as [string, ...string[]]
);

export const SubscriptionEnum = pgEnum(
  "Subscription",
  subscription.map((s: constants) => s.value) as [string, ...string[]]
);

export const PaymentTypeEnum = pgEnum(
  "PaymentType",
  paymentType.map((p: constants) => p.value) as [string, ...string[]]
);


export const users = pgTable("Users", {
  id: text("ID").notNull().primaryKey(), // firebase auth uid
  name: text("Name").notNull(),
  email: text("Email").notNull().unique(),
  role: UserRoleEnum("Role").default("customer"),
  registration_date: timestamp("Registration_Date", {
    mode: "date",
  }).defaultNow(),
});


export const vendors = pgTable("Vendors", {
  id: serial("ID").notNull().primaryKey(),
  user_id: text("User_ID")
    .notNull()
    .references(() => users.id, { onDelete: "cascade" }),
  is_approved: boolean("Is_Approved").default(false),
  subscription_type: SubscriptionEnum("Subscription_Type")
    .default("Free Trial")
    .notNull(),
});

export const restaurants = pgTable("Restaurants", {
  id: serial("ID").notNull().primaryKey(),
  vendor_id: integer("Vendor_ID")
    .notNull()
    .references(() => vendors.id, { onDelete: "cascade" }),
  // order_phases : [{name: "lunch", from: "10:00", to: "09:00", delivery_time: "1 PM - 2 PM", }, {name: "dinner", from: "10:00", to: "10:00", delivery_time: "7 PM - 8 PM", }, ],
  order_phases: jsonb("Order_Phases").notNull(),
  delivery_location: jsonb("Delivery_Location").notNull(),
});

export type MyDatabase = NodePgDatabase<{
  Users: typeof users;
  Customers: typeof customers;
  Vendors: typeof vendors;
  Payments: typeof payments;
  Payments_DuitNow: typeof payments_duitnow;
  Payments_CreditCard: typeof payments_creditcard;
  Payments_Bank: typeof payments_bank;
  Vouchers: typeof vouchers;
  Comments: typeof comments;
  Restaurants: typeof restaurants;
  Menus: typeof menus;
  Receipts: typeof receipts;
  Carts: typeof carts;
  Refunds: typeof refunds;
}>;
```

this is my relation.ts at @lib/relation.ts

```js
import { users, vendors, restaurants } from "@/lib/schema";

import { relations } from "drizzle-orm";

export const usersRelations = relations(users, ({ one, many }) => ({
  // a user can be  a vendor
  vendor: one(vendors, {
    fields: [users.id],
    references: [vendors.user_id],
  }),
}));

export const vendorsRelations = relations(vendors, ({ one, many }) => ({
  // a vendor is a user
  user: one(users, {
    fields: [vendors.user_id],
    references: [users.id],
  }),

  // a vendor can have multiple restaurants
  restaurants: many(restaurants),
}));

export const restaurantsRelations = relations(restaurants, ({ one, many }) => ({
  // a restaurant is owned by a vendor
  vendor: one(vendors, {
    fields: [restaurants.vendor_id],
    references: [vendors.id],
  }),
}));
```

this is my db.ts at @lib/db.ts

```js
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/postgres-js";
import postgres from "postgres";
import type { MyDatabase } from "@/lib/schema";
import * as schema from "@/lib/schema";

export const connectionString = process.env.SECRET_SUPABASE_URL || import.meta.env.SECRET_SUPABASE_URL;

if (!connectionString) {
  throw new Error("DATABASE_URL is missing");
}

declare global {
  var db: MyDatabase | undefined;
}

let db: MyDatabase;

if (!global.db) {
  // Disable prefetch as it is not supported for "Transaction" pool mode
  const client = postgres(connectionString, { prepare: false });

  global.db = drizzle(client, { logger: true, schema });
}

db = global.db;

export default db;
```

Even though I can just use db.select to achieve what I wanted, but I wonder if I'm using the findMany correctly to achieve the same thing and is my setup correct?

Answer (score 0):

I just need to make sure the **tablename** in `query.tablename` matches the **tablename** in `export const tablename = pgTable`